# Is $\Big| \frac{\zeta(1/2 + ix)}{\zeta(1/2 - ix)} \Big| \equiv 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, riemann-zeta

Suppose analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(z)$, defined for all $z \in \mathbb C$, and let $x \in \mathbb R$.

Then, $\Big| \frac{\zeta(1/2 + ix)}{\zeta(1/2 - ix)}\Big| \equiv 1$? How would one show this identity?

Comment: Note that $\zeta(t) \in \mathbb{R}$ if $t \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$.

Comment: You can use that for $\Re(s) > 0, 2^{1-s}-1 \ne 0$ : $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \eta(s)$ where $\eta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$. More generally, since $\zeta(s) = \overline{\zeta(\overline{s})}$ for every $\Re(s) > 1$, by analytic continuation it stays true for every $s$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\zeta$ function is real for real parameters, hence
$$ \forall w\in\mathbb{C},\qquad \zeta(\overline{w}) = \overline{\zeta(w)} $$
implying the statement, follows from [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle).